# Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

When I create a new project in pyharm, I also create venv. after which I try to install "pip install django" and it gives an error that it has already been downloaded. But issues in another location. for example the project is on my way С:\Python\drf. and venv in С:\Python\drf\venv
A is install in c:\users\qqwee\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages. In setting in python interpreter i'm choice С:\Python\drf\venv\Scripts\python.exe

Comment: You don't have administrative privileges while installing any dependency from pip. Therefore that place is not writable. So, pip is downloading and installing package at different location.

Comment: Where do you execute `pip install django`?